# iOS : Developing for HealthKit, DOB, Height etc coming back as nil

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

So, I have been tasked with learning HealthKit, seems fairly straight forward.  Started building my own app, can get steps etc.  However I can't get date of birth, sex, etc.  They are always returned as nil

I then downloaded Apple's sample app Fit, again comes back with nothing.

**I have authorised both apps and created a medical id in health**  I am based in the UK? is it a us only thing?

```
func readProfile() -> ( age:Int?,  biologicalsex:HKBiologicalSexObject?, bloodtype:HKBloodTypeObject?)
  {
    var error:NSError?
    var age:Int?

    // 1. Request birthday and calculate age
    if let birthDay = healthKitStore.dateOfBirthWithError(&error)
    {
      let today = NSDate()
      let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
      let differenceComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(.YearCalendarUnit, fromDate: birthDay, toDate: today, options: NSCalendarOptions(0) )
      age = differenceComponents.year
    }
    if error != nil {
      println("Error reading Birthday: \(error)")
    }

    // 2. Read biological sex
    var biologicalSex:HKBiologicalSexObject? = healthKitStore.biologicalSexWithError(&error);
    if error != nil {
      println("Error reading Biological Sex: \(error)")
    }
    // 3. Read blood type
    var bloodType:HKBloodTypeObject? = healthKitStore.bloodTypeWithError(&error);
    if error != nil {
      println("Error reading Blood Type: \(error)")
    }

    // 4. Return the information read in a tuple
    return (age, biologicalSex, bloodType)
  }
```

Comment: we do check if the error has been set if error != nil {
      println("Error reading Blood Type: \(error)")
    }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configuring Medical ID does not populate values for any HealthKit types.  Try setting values for each type using the Health Data tab in the Health app.

Comment: The medical ID does populate DOfB and blood type etc?  this is the data I cant see?

Comment: It still returns me nil.. How to populate data in Health App ? Profile is set, no other option left in app

Comment: It would've been useful if Apple mentioned this minor fact somewhere! I just wasted 2 hours banging my head not knowing this fact! Thanks alot.